# "Share As Locator" option is disabled in the ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

How to enable the "Share As Locator" option in ArcGIS Pro?

What could be the reason for it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the [Share a locator](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geocoding/share-a-locator.htm) page of the ArcGIS Pro Online Help it says:

> If you are a member of a custom role in ArcGIS Enterprise 10.6 or
> later, be sure the administrator has granted you the Publish
> server-based layers privilege.

Consequently, I think you should assess whether that may apply to you.